# $S = A\setminus B$, $C \subset B$, then $S \mathrel{\square} A\setminus C$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Given $S = A\setminus B$, $C \subset B$, what should be inserted at $\square$, here: $S \mathrel{\square}  A\setminus C$?

Where $\square$ could be $\subseteq$ or $\supseteq$

Comment: $\subseteq$ has a lot of analogies with $\le$. How does $S = A - B$ compare to $A - C$, when $C \le B$? (Alternatively, of course, write down an explicit, small example of such a triplet $A, B, C$ of sets).

Comment: $S\supset A$ \ $C$.  Suppose $S$ is all cats, $B$ is all white animals, $C$ is all white female animals.

Comment: is  this a question, or a challenge? Either way, it's answered below.

Comment: Have you tried some examples? Writing a proof? Something?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yeah intuitively it makes sense it should be $\subseteq$, but I am not well versed in doing formal proofs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S=A-B$ and $C \subset B$.

We will show that $S \subset A-C$

Let $s \in S$. Then $s \in A-B$. Then $s \in A$, $s \notin B$. By contrapositive, $s \notin C$[ $s \in C \implies S \in B$, so the contrapositive is the prior statement]. Hence $s \in A-C$, so $S \subset A-C$.

$A-C \subseteq S$ for only the trivial case where $B=C$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, you get $S$ from $A$ by removing everything that is in $B$. When you do $S\setminus C$ you remove less, so you should get a bigger set.

Formally: let $x\in S$; then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$. Since $C\subset B$, we also have $x\notin C$. Thus $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Therefore $x\in A\setminus C$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the facts

- $C \subseteq B$, then $B^c \subseteq C^c$. (equality of 1st is equivalent to equality  of 2nd)
- $A\setminus B=A\cap B^c$.

We have:

If $C \subseteq B$, then $A\setminus B \subseteq A\setminus C.$ (equality of 1st is equivalent to equality  of 2nd.)